# Coverting NSInputStream ans NSOutputStream to System.IO.Stream - Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, stream, type-conversion

I am currently busy developing an iOS app using MonoTouch.

When connecting to an External Accessory and establishing a EASession, I need to pass the NSInputStream and NSOutputStream to another method expexting System.IO.Stream for both input and output streams.

I am not sure how to proceed with this as I am using some C# libraries that are written to be platform independent and therefore I cannot change the method to expect NSInputStream/NSOutputStream.

What is the best way to convert these streams to System.IO.Stream?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I got it working properly. If someone has any suggestions please let me know.

The InputStream is pretty straight forward but the OutputStream is a little different. The code below will allow you to call both Write() end WriteByte() methods. I've left in the Console.WriteLine() for people to see how this works.

InputStream:

```
class CustomInputStream : System.IO.Stream
{

    NSInputStream input_stream;

    public CustomInputStream (NSInputStream str)
    {
        input_stream = str;
    }

    public override void Flush ()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (offset != 0)
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        return input_stream.Read (buffer, (uint)count);
    }

    public override long Seek (long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override void SetLength (long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override void Write (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override bool CanRead {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override long Length {
        get {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
    }

    public override long Position {
        get {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
        set {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
    }

}
```

OutputStream:

```
class CustomOutputStream : System.IO.Stream
{

    NSOutputStream output_stream;
    List<byte> buffer;

    public CustomOutputStream (NSOutputStream str)
    {
        output_stream = str;
        buffer = new List<byte>();
    }

    public override void Flush ()
    {
        Write(buffer.ToArray(),0,buffer.Count);
        buffer.Clear();
    }

    public override int Read (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {       
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override long Seek (long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override void SetLength (long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override void Write (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (offset != 0)
            throw new NotSupportedException ();

        int sent = 0;
        var stillToSend = new byte[buffer.Length-offset];
        buffer.CopyTo(stillToSend, offset);

        Console.WriteLine("out while begin (buffer: {0})",buffer.LongLength);   
        while (count > 0)
        {       
            if (output_stream.HasSpaceAvailable()) 
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("in while has space");
                var bytesWritten = output_stream.Write(buffer, (uint)count);
                if (bytesWritten == -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(@"write error");
                    break;
                }
                else if (bytesWritten > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Bytes written: "+ bytesWritten.ToString());
                    count -= bytesWritten;
                    if (0 == count)
                        break;

                    var temp = new List<byte>();
                    for (var i=bytesWritten; i<stillToSend.Length; i++)
                    {
                        temp.Add(stillToSend[i]);
                    }
                    stillToSend = temp.ToArray();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("in while has NO space");
            }
        }


    }
    public override void WriteByte (byte value)
    {

        buffer.Add(value);

    }

    public override bool CanRead {
        get {
            return false;

        }
    }


    public override bool CanSeek {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override long Length {
        get {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
    }

    public override long Position {
        get {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
        set {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no built-in way to convert NSInputStream/NSOutputStream to a System.IO.Stream, but you can easily write your own System.IO.Stream wrapper, something like this:

```
class MyInputStream : System.IO.Stream
{
    NSInputStream input_stream;
    public MyInputStream (NSInputStream str)
    {
        input_stream = str;
    }

    public override void Flush ()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override int Read (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (offset != 0)
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        return input_stream.Read (buffer, count);
    }

    public override long Seek (long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override void SetLength (long value)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override void Write (byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException ();
    }

    public override bool CanRead {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override long Length {
        get {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
    }

    public override long Position {
        get {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
        set {
            throw new NotSupportedException ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Makes sense but now I'm stuck with the following: The framework uses the Stream's BeginRead(IAsyncResult) and EndRead(IAsyncResult) methods... Do you have advice on how to go forth with that?

Comment: System.IO.Stream contains a default implementation of BeginRead and EndRead (which is synchronous) - does this not work for you?